# Filter out some plugin action in wp head / wp_footer

Tags: filters, conditional-tags, wp-head

I am using a plugin called "syntaxhighlighter".

**I know not to ask for plugin specific questions** but rather how to filter out action added to the wp_head / wp_footer conditionally...

**This is a part of the plugin script:**

```
// Outputting SyntaxHighlighter's JS and CSS
add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'output_header_placeholder' ), 15 );
add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'maybe_output_scripts' ), 15 );
```

**Now, i would like to add a filter that says:**

```
if(is_home() || is_category()) {
   // REMOVE THOSE SCRIPS
}
```

.
I dont want to change that plugin code becouse i would have
to remmember to do it again when it updates...

How can i filter those actions out when needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (untested):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 
   function(){
       // your conditions:
       if( is_home() || is_category() )
       {
           // access the global SyntaxHighlighter object instantiated at 'init'.
           global $SyntaxHighlighter;

           // remove your action hooks:
           remove_action( 'wp_head',    
                           array( $SyntaxHighlighter, 'output_header_placeholder' ),
                           15 );
           remove_action( 'wp_footer', 
                           array( $SyntaxHighlighter, 'maybe_output_scripts' ),
                           15 );
       }
   }
);
```

to remove these action hooks conditionally with template tags. We use the `wp_head` action with the default priority `10`.

You can use other hooks but they must fire earlier than `wp_head` with priority `15` and after the `$SyntaxHighlighter` object creation via the *init* hook.

You must also make sure that your template tags, you want to use in your conditional checks, are available in the hook you choose.

Comment: intresting ;) going to test it. Thanks mate. would be back soon

Comment: Works like a charm... should have known this alone ;) thanks for your help

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you, cheers.